# float:left insive li in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-lists

When I make float: left to block inside

Chrome displays it incorrectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/5dLarwsk/

```
<body>
<ol>
    <li>
        <div class="input"></div>
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat ea, obcaecati tempore omnis voluptatum cum blanditiis expeditaporro soluta praesentium.</div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="input"></div>
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat ea, obcaecati tempore omnis voluptatum cum blanditiis expeditaporro soluta praesentium.</div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="input"></div>
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat ea, obcaecati tempore omnis voluptatum cum blanditiis expeditaporro soluta praesentium.</div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

```
    .input {
    display: inline-block; 
    background: #999; 
    width: 15px; 
    height: 15px; 
    border-radius: 2px; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    float: left;
}
.text {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

How to solve problem?

Comment: What does chrome display that's incorrect?

Comment: Chrome puts list numbers inside to .input block, but should put near .input blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decrease your html markup by using [counter-reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset) and [counter-increament](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment)

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: section;
}
ol li {
  position: relative;
}
ol li:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section);
  background: #999;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -28px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat ea, obcaecati tempore omnis voluptatum cum blanditiis expeditaporro soluta praesentium.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat ea, obcaecati tempore omnis voluptatum cum blanditiis expeditaporro soluta praesentium.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat ea, obcaecati tempore omnis voluptatum cum blanditiis expeditaporro soluta praesentium.</li>
</ol>
```